# Removing older versions of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

I have installed up to 2.6.1 of QGIS on my computer.

Is it recommended that i remove all older versions or will it cause conflicts if they remain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only conflict that will arise will be between plugins used between different QGIS verions. In other words, if you use the latest OpenLayers plugin designed for QGIS 2.6, you will not be able to use it for QGIS 2.4.

There should not be any other kind of conflicts. I have several QGIS versions installed which all work perfectly fine. So it's perfectly fine for you to keep different QGIS versions, just keep an eye out for the plugin versions as they may not be compatible with an older QGIS.

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to the [answer of user @Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/134532/115):

If you want to work with different versions of QGIS on your computer and don't want to store the plugins from different versions in the same folder you can also use seperate folders for your different QGIS versions to store the options and configs. By doing this you can avoid conflicts with plugins that are not suitable for both (or all) versions of QGIS that you use.

Just edit your shortcut to qgis by adding --optionspath and --configpath, for example to:

```
"C:\your_path_to_qgis\bin\qgis.bat --optionspath "T:\qgisconfig\2_6" --configpath "T:\qgisconfig\2_6"
```

[image]

Then your options and configs will be stored there (including your plugins):

[image]