# Uninstalling old QGIS versions to save disk space?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I would like to clean up disk space used by old versions of QGIS.

Can I use the Windows Uninstaller without damaging the current installation or should I only delete the directory in the Programs folder?

The screen shot of my installed versions is shown in the picture.

[image: List of Installed QGIS]

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using uninstaller to remove the versions you do not need and then manually checking to see if the associated folders were automatically deleted. If they were not, then delete them yourself. That has been my practice and i have not had any bad experiences.

Answer (score 3):

Based on responses to [Do I need to remove older versions of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134531) you can consider a couple of options:

The only conflict will be in the plugins of the different versions, otherwise you should be fine. I would recommend to back up any data as you would typically with any work you do.